# Closure: Should you visit Newfoundland to leaf-peep, when it's in the Boreal Shield?

Tags: discussion

I've since edited [Should you visit Newfoundland to leaf-peep, when it's in the Boreal Shield?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/102226/13759), but am not sure why it was closed originally?

Comment: How is the classification of a biome a travel topic?

Comment: @choster My question isn't about `classification of a biome`.

Comment: It reads like one to me: *Do the following recommendations contradict Newfoundland's belonging to the terrestrial ecozone Boreal Shield?*